# React vs react native

Tags: react-native

I have switched to making cross platform apps (not made one though) using react native. I just wanted an answer to my question of the difference between react and react native. I searched the net but found no appropriate answer.

Comment: React is a view library used to build front end apps on web and mobile using JSX. React-native is a tool used to build mobile apps that compile down to native code.

Answer (score 0):

React is a web framework i.e, it is used to build front end for a website not an app but
react-native is used to create cross platform apps, though react-native is written in a similar way as react. We use many things from react in react-native but there are also many differences like; we can use DOM elements like `<div>`, `<p>` etc in react but we cannot use them in react-native. There are different components for that. E.g, we have `<View>` instead of `<div>` etc.

So in nutshell, react runs in a browser but react-native can run without browser as a native app on android, ios, windows phone etc.